# Details page content based on url

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have a list of events using the following code:

```
@foreach($entries as $entry)

<a href="{{ url('events/eventdetails', [$entry->id]) }}"> {{$entry->title}} </a><br>

@endforeach
```

SO on the details page the ID is displaying in URL like 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/eventdetails/1

However the content on this page is not currently specific to that ID... something I want to achieve.

I can display the ID on the details page using `$entry->id` but I don't know how to cross check the ID of the page with the event ID to only display content relating to the one ID.

When I do `<?php print_r($entries);?>` I get something like this (cut down example of the code which in full shows all entries)...

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Event Object ( [connection:protected] => sqlite [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => Spring Festival
```

Controller:

```
class EventsController extends Controller
{
    public function displayEvent()

    {
        $entries = Event::get();
        return view('eventdisplay', ['entries' => $entries]);

    }
public function displayEventDetails()

{

    $entries = Event::get();
  //  $entries->id = $id;
    return view('eventdetails', ['entries' => $entries]);

}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('events/eventdetails/{id}', 'EventsController@displayEventDetails')->name('displayEventDetails');
```

Comment: Why use $entry->id in bracket ?

Comment: How does your URL look like?

Comment: Annapurna I have updated the question to include this.

Comment: ramin ashrafimanesh it works without them also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function for handling the details view is missing the URL parameter as a variable passed to the function:

```
public function displayEventDetails(){...}
// should be
public function displayEventDetails($eventId){...}
```

So that you can filter your `Event` model to a single id:

```
$entries = Event::where("id", "=", $eventId)->first();
// or
$entries = Event::find($eventId);
// or
$entries = Event::findOrFail($eventId);
// etc, etc
```

Your url looks correct to handle this, as `{id}` specifies that the parameter should be available to the controller as a variable.

Also I believe that `Event` is a reserved keyword in Laravel, so you should use namespacing to avoid conflicts there, or rename your model.

Comment: You star! Thank you. And yes I recently discovered the issue of naming as event and will rectify this shortly. Thank you very much Tim.